# How to get the SQL content of the stored procedure in Delphi code?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

I'm debugging Delphi code with Delphi 7 IDE, the code is not mine. My goal is to understand how this code works. This will help me to write my application which will interface with this code.

I never used Delphi in my life. I'm a C, C++, C# programmer.

I'm able to see the output (result) of the stored procedure but I need to see the content of the stored procedure (I mean the SQL statement). I looked in SQL Server side but I didn't find anything.

The stored procedure is called in this function :

```
function TDBDM.getID( prKeyName : string ) : integer;
begin
  try
    spGetSN.Parameters.ParamValues['@prKeyname'] := prKeyName;
    spGetSN.open;
    result := spGetSN.Fields[0].AsInteger;
  finally
    spGetSN.close;
  end;
end;
```

and the stored procedure 'spGetSN' is declared here :

```
unit dmDB;
interface
uses
   SysUtils, Classes, Forms, ADODB, DB, TypInfo, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
   Controls,Registry, Windows;
type
   eConnectionType = (ctSN);

TDBDM = class(TDataModule)
    ADOConnectionSN: TADOConnection;
    spGetSN: TADOStoredProc;
    ADOQueryGetPartNoFromRMA: TADOQuery;
    ADOQueryGetPartNoFromOrder: TADOQuery;
    procedure ADOConnectionSNBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
 private
    { Private declarations }
    function GetConnection( prConnectionType : eConnectionType ) :   
    TADOConnection;
 public
    { Public declarations }

    function getID( prKeyName : string ) : integer;
    function getSN( prKeyName : string ) : string;
    function getCommaValues( prSelect : string; prConnection :  
        eConnectionType = ctSN ) : string;

    property pConnection[prType : eConnectionType] : TADOConnection read 
       GetConnection; default;
 end;

 var
    DBDM: TDBDM;

 implementation
 uses dmRegistryClasses;
 {$R *.dfm}
```

The text of the object TADOSTOREDPROC 'spGetSN' as defined in the IDE is :

```
  object spGetSN: TADOStoredProc
    Connection = ADOConnectionSN
    ProcedureName = 'spGetSN;1'
    Parameters = <
      item
        Name = '@RETURN_VALUE'
        DataType = ftInteger
        Direction = pdReturnValue
        Precision = 10
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = '@prKeyname'
        Attributes = [paNullable]
        DataType = ftWideString
        Size = 30
        Value = Null
      end>
    Left = 268
    Top = 80
  end
```

How can I print or watch the SQL code of this stored procedure in Delphi debugger? Thanks

Comment: You can't easily get the source code of the stored procedure from inside a Delphi application.  It's far easier just to look at the SP from inside Sql Server Management Studio:  Do you not have access to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query the `sys.sql_modules` table e.g.:

```
function MSSQL_GetModuleText(conn: TADOConnection; const ModuleName: WideString): WideString;
var
  SQL: WideString;
  rs: Variant;
begin
  SQL := Format('SELECT [definition] FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE [object_id]=OBJECT_ID(N''%s'')', [ModuleName]);
  rs := conn.Execute(SQL);
  Result := VarToWideStr(rs.Fields[0]); 
end;
```

Usage:

```
S := MSSQL_GetModuleText(ADOConnectionSN, 'dbo.spGetSN');
```

Comment: Yes works. thanks. I have to add Variants unit in use statement.

Answer (score 4):

The following should give you an idea how to do it:

- Add a TAdoQuery called AdoQuerySP to your form and set its connection to whatever AdoConnection component you're using at the moment.
- Add a TMemo to the form.
- Add a TButton to the form and set its OnClick handler to execute the code below (after changing `checklibuse` to the name of your SP).

Code:

```
procedure TForm1.GetSPDefinition;
var
  S : String;
begin
  S := '';
  AdoQuerySP.Sql.Text := 'exec sp_helptext checklibuse';  //  sp_helptext
  //  is a Sql Server system stored proc to retrieve the definition of 
  // a stored proc.  The definition is returned as a series of rows which need to be 
  //  concatenated together as in the `while ...` loop below.
  AdoQuerySP.Open;
  while not AdoQuerySP.Eof do begin
    if S <> '' then
      S := #13#10 + S;
    S := S + AdoQuerySP.FieldByName('Text').AsString;
    AdoQuerySP.Next;
  end;
  //  The retrieved definition is typically preceded by a number of blank lines
  //  which the call to Trim() remove.
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Trim(S);
end;
```

Comment: Cool it works. thank you very much.  But Why I cannot find this stored procedure inside MS SQL SERVER ?

Comment: I'm using MS-SQL server 2014, I searched in the explorer window. Databases->MyDatabase->Programmability->Stored Procedures.  Also I tried this Query : use [MyDataBase]
go
exec sp_helptext MyStoredProcedure
go. I cannot find this Stored procedure inside MS SQL SERVER. Could we define Stored procedure inside the Delphi code ?

Comment: Check your connection options. Seems to me application is connecting to real server while you are connecting by SSMS to a local Expess instance.

Comment: As you didn't create the SP, the only plausible reason I can think of that you can't see the SP in SSMS is maybe you're connecting to the server from an account with sufficient rights, but try googling as this seems to be a frequent prob with several causes.  Fwiw, I can see SPs on my own servers.  You can certainly create an SP in Delphi code - create a Sql script that will do it, assign its text to an AdoQuery and then call .ExecSql on it.